# How to specify a prediction using statsmodels mnlogit model?

Tags: python, pandas, prediction, statsmodels

I am running a `mnlogit` regression and I would like to do some predictions.
My data is on a pandas `DataFrame` named state containing the two columns age and final_state (and others).

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
result = smf.mnlogit(
    formula = 'final_state ~ age ',
    data = state[['age', 'final_state']],
    ).fit()

params = result.params
print result.summary()
```

I can do the prediction on the sample used for estimation by running:

```
prediction = result.predict()
```

However if I want to use a subsample or any other data as in the following lines:

```
prediction = result.predict(exog = state[['age']].query('age > 80'))
prediction = result.predict(exog = dict(age = [80, 90]))
prediction = result.predict(
    exog = dict(age = state[['age']].query('age > 80').values))
prediction = result.predict(exog = state[['age']])
```

I always end up with the same following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py", line 772, in predict
exog = dmatrix(self.model.data.design_info.builder,
AttributeError: 'PandasData' object has no attribute 'design_info'
```

How can I compute a prediction for a subsample or artificial data?

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20724919/pandas-dataframe-attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-design-inf) was given in the first comment by jeffrey_the_wind, Thanks.

Comment: looks like this answer might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20724919/pandas-dataframe-attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-design-inf  What i was thinking your DF isn't formatted compatibly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I've just submitted this as a bug](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3958). Turns out that there is no unit test for formula behavior within `mnlogit`

Not transforming the data (and instead manually adding the constant) is a workaround:

```
from statsmodels.tools import add_constant
result.predict(add_constant(state['age']), transform=False)
```